# Turn off the https requirement for https gated web APIs in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, https, webxr

[Many modern Web APIs are gated by the browser to be HTTPS only](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Secure_Contexts/features_restricted_to_secure_contexts). This is good for users but can make developing painful. During development I'd like to be able to turn off that requirement just for testing.

Is there a flag I can set (about:config in firefox, about:flags in chrome) or a command line parameter I can pass in to turn off that requirement so I can test without having to setup https certs and add them to the browser?

Note: I understand the https requirement is dropped for localhost but I'm often hosting on one machine (like a laptop) and testing on another (like an Android device) or a different desktop. I know I can generate a local cert and run a server that supports https. I then have to deal with security warnings on the browsers (invalid cert) and/or add the private certs to all the devices OR I have to register a domain solely for the purpose of getting a valid cert via letsencrypt. For my own dev I'd just like to temporarily turn off that check in the browser if possible. Of course what I actually serve to users will be https but during dev if I could turn off that requirement things would be so much easier.

In my particular case I'm trying to use [WebXR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebXR_Device_API) so dev happens on my laptop but actual testing happens on an Android device where the page is served from my laptop.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome has a developer setting **Insecure origins treated as secure** in chrome://flags/, this is a text field where you can add a list of origins treated as secure for development purposes. (Via https://github.com/immersive-web/webxr/issues/60)

[image]

Comment: i'm confused how this is helpful. When I tried with an ip address it didn't seem to work. If I use a domain name then need my android device to see that domain name which adds a bunch of hurdles for a locally served web server. Is there more to this?

Answer (score 0):

One solution suggested [here](https://github.com/immersive-web/webxr/issues/60#issuecomment-570263477) is to use Chrome's port forwarding

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/local-server

That works for Chrome desktop to Android

On your desktop you tell desktop chrome what site at what port to forward to your android device at another port. That site can be a server on the internet or a server running locally on your desktop. On the android device you can then access that site at `http://localhost:<port-you-specified>`. https requirements are dropped for locahost host so you can now use the APIs that were restricted otherwise.

Comment: Is this supposed to be your answer to the question or a comment or an addition to your question?

Comment: It does answer the question, the https requirements are dropped for localhost, the chrome port forwarding feature means your android device can see a server that your desktop chrome can see via localhost on the android device. It still like to find a solution for firefox.